# What kind of ADC noise is this?

Tags: pcb-design, adc

I recently designed a PCB board that collect AC signal using following components:
MCP3204 for ADC sampling
INA128 for signal conditioning
TL431 for voltage reference

Everything is good, most of the noise is below 30 steps when nothing is connected (12 bit ADC, 4096 steps, 5V reference, so is about 30mV of noise, is ok though)
But the thing is, when I measure the signal of the 2.5V reference (using mcp3204 on the same PCB board), it return strange kind of output:
[image]

where the spikes could reach 100 to 150mV, I tried replacing TL431 for LM385 or LM336, it is still the same, even worse than the performance of TL431.
the frequency of the spike is around 150 to 200Hz, here is my layout and schematic:
NOTE: although in the schematic I connected 1 TL431 to 4 INA128, in reality I only connect it with 1 INA128. When I use a jumper to connect voltage reference directly to MCP3204, the effect is still the same.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there anything I can do to remove the noise? many thanks

Update: I added more images to clarify my situation
Overview of signal with and without voltage reference
[image]

Signal with voltage reference, notice the spikes
[image]

Signal without voltage reference (okay, it looks a bit noisy, but on the grand scheme, 30mV noise for me is acceptable (when compared with that of voltage reference))
[image]

Comment: How many PCB layers? How does Vref, the analog input and the buffered signal entering the ADC look on your scope?

Comment: Are you using the standard Arduino library for talking to the ADC?

Comment: @winny there is only 2 layers as I etched the PCB myself. I don't have the scope with me though, so I cannot find out their true signal.

Comment: @PaulUszak I used esp32-arduino framework to talk to the ADC, it means that I use SPI.transfer() function,  I didn't use any particular library

Comment: Let's try to rule out EMI: do you still get noise with the WiFi off on the ESP?

Comment: Also according to TL431 datasheet it will not be stable with 100nF capacitor as per your schematic.

Comment: @bobflux yeah I did tried using 10nF capacitor. It did help in term of oscillation, but the spike is still there. As you can see in the updated images, the spikes only happen with voltage reference signal, not the non connected ones.

Comment: also, I've broken the ESP32 micro usb pin, so cannot test with WiFi off yet.

Comment: Try https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/mcp3208/.  This is well tested.

Answer (score 4):

> What kind of ADC noise is this?

Notice how there are apparently non-random "bands" of amplitude on that noise, around which many samples vary by only a small amount.

I have draw some lines on your original plot, to show them:

[image: original noise plot with added lines indicating non-random value ranges]

When I see this type of non-random pattern, the cause is not analog noise getting into the ADC, but is "digital" in origin. Examples of causes for similar patterns have included:

- Wrongly reconstructing the final value from multiple 8-bit ADC register reads; or
- Wrongly reading the 8-bit ADC registers in the first place (even before reconstructing them in a larger (e.g. 12-bit) value), e.g. big-endian vs. little-endian, or off-by-one bit etc., so that a small analog change caused a much larger change in the *apparent* digital value.

There was a previous similar question here, which I have spent a long time searching for today, but cannot find :-( IIRC it involved reconstructing a multi-byte value from an I2C ADC, and the sequence of ADC reads was somehow incorrect (or the C code to shift and OR them into a 32-bit number was wrong - I can't remember the exact details) and the apparent "noise pattern" looked very similar, with these non-random bands of values.

One approach is to review the raw register values from the ADC (don't attempt to plot them), and look for patterns in the numbers e.g. do you see lots of values close to a 2^n value? I think looking at the raw data for the plot in your question, would be a good use of your time.

One final point: MCU communication via SPI with the [MCP3204](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21298e.pdf) is not trivial, as it is not designed to output a multiple of 8 bits, yet most MCUs are designed for that. (I don't use SPI on the ESP32, but since you're using that MCU I expect you will know the details.) I would use a scope or logic analyzer to carefully review the SPI signals during the reading of the ADC data, ensuring that the signal sequence and timing match Figure 6-1 on page 21 of that MCP3204 datasheet linked above. It would be easy to introduce bugs in the reading of that ADC's output.

Comment: ...why would Microchip design the MCP3204 like that, I wonder? You'd think it would output two bytes, just with the upper four bits all zero or containing status info or something.

Comment: @Hearth - Hi, Agreed completely! The MCP3204 datasheet says rev. A was November 1998, so whatever decisions led to that register / protocol design, could be lost in the mists of time...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, but in the update section of question, I've added more picture of signal gotten from channel without voltage reference, and signal gotten when I added AC signal (still without TL431 or the likes), as you can see, the data looks clean enough, only vary about 30mV.

Comment: Things only escalate when I add voltage reference to INA128 ref pin, or directly connect it to MCP3204 input pin. So I don't think the problem is digital though.

Comment: @HaiDangMinh - Hi, (a) You said: "*in the update section of question, I've added more picture [...]*" What "update section" do you mean? Your question has not been edited / updated since you wrote it. Did you update it somewhere else and forget to update it here, perhaps? Of course we would like to see more test results. (b) I am not clear what test you were doing which produced the unlabeled plot currently in the question. However it's possible for the problem to be as I describe, only above a certain voltage (depending on how the ADC output is being "corrupted") e.g. above TL431 o/p (2.5 V?)

Comment: @SamGibson hi, I've just added more images after adding comment. the original signal is the signal from the TL431 (and LM336, LM385, all have similar kind of result, just different in terms of the magnitude of spikes) when I plug its output directly to the input of MCP3204. The result is the same when I connect its output to Vref pin of INA128, and plug INA128 output to MCP3204 input pin.